Question about Gradient-like vector field
If $X$ is a smooth vector field on a $n$-dim manifold $M$ , then in a co-ordinate chart $U$ ,  $X$ can be written as $X=\sum_{i=1} ^{n}a_{i}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ where $\forall i$, $a_{i}$ are smooth function defined on the co-ordinate chart $U$.
Suppose $f: M \to R$ be a smooth function . Define a vector field $X_f = \sum_{i=1} ^{n}\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_{i}} \frac {\partial }{\partial x_{i}}$. This vector field is called gradient vector field of $f$. For a Morse function $f:M \to R$ , by Morse lemma there exists a co-ordinate neighbor of a critical point $p \in M$ , where $f$ has a form : $f(x_{1} , \ldots x_{n}) = -x_{1}^{2}- \ldots - x_{\lambda}^{2}+x_{\lambda + 1}^{2} + \ldots + x_{n}^{2}$ where $\lambda $ is the index of the critical point. So in this co-ordinate neighborhood $X_{f} = -2x_{1} \frac {\partial}{\partial x_{1} }-\ldots-2x_{\lambda}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{\lambda}}+2x_{\lambda +1}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{\lambda+1}}+\ldots+2x_{n}\frac {\partial}{\partial x_{n}}$ .
Now , if $X$ is a smooth vector field and $f:M \to R $ is a Morse function , then we call $X$ is a gradient like vector field of $f$ if the following hold :
(1) $X . f > 0 $ away from the critical point;
(2) There exists a neighborhood $V$ for the critical point $p \in M$ , where $X=X_f$ .
I have read about existence of gradient -like vector field of a Morse function defined on a compact manifold in "An Introduction to Morse Theory" by Yukio Matsumoto . The theorem is the following :
Theorem 2.30. : Suppose that $ f : M \to R $ is a Morse function on a compact manifold $M$. Then there exists a gradient-like vector field $X$ for $f$.
My question is the following :
Is the converse part of this theorem true ? i.e if $f: M \to R$ be a smooth function on compact manifold $M$ and $X$ be a gradient-like vector field on $M$ ,then can we prove that $f$ is Morse on $M$ or by modifying $f$ can we get a new function $g:M \to R $ which is Morse on $M$ ?
